# Python: creating a output CSV from multiple ones. Vlookup

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to fetch data from one CSV file and put the respective information of that data which is in another CSV file and merge them in a Output file.

lets say this is my lookup file:

Name.csv:

```
+------+
|CI_Name|
+------+
| a    |
| b    |
| c    |
| ...  |
+------+
```

This is another csv file from where I will get the related information of the server, Ip address, etc

Main.csv

```
+------+--------+------------+
|CI_Name | Server | IP-Address |
+------+--------+------------+
| a    |        |            |
| b    |        |            |
| c    |        |            |
| ...  |        |            |
+------+--------+------------+
```

What I want is to merge this two information into a new excel sheet(csv), basically a VLOOKUP, Please help Python Coders! I need a code and explanation, so that I will be able to do Vlookup in future with ease.

This is the code that I have tried:

```
import csv

with open('Name.csv', 'r') as csvinput:
    with open('Main.csv', 'r') as lookuplist:
        with open('Output.csv', 'w') as output:

            reader = csv.reader(lookuplist)
            reader1 = csv.reader(csvinput)
            writer = csv.writer(output)

            for CI_Name in reader1:
                for SERVER, FQDN, AUTOMATION_ADMINISTRATOR, IP_ADDRESS, PRIMARY1, MHT_1, MHT_2, MHT_3, MHT_4 in reader: #this are the columnss i need to match from the Main and import it to the output.csv
                    if CI_Name[0] == FQDN[0]:
                        CI_Name.append(FQDN[1:])
                        writer.writerow(CI_Name)
```

The Error that I'm getting is:

```
for SERVER, FQDN, AUTOMATION_ADMINISTRATOR, IP_ADDRESS, PRIMARY1, MHT_1, MHT_2, MHT_3, MHT_4 in reader:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: I'd recommending using pandas.

Comment: Python 2.7 is what I am using. But I have no alternatives. So will have to script in this one only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not worked specifically for CSV, however I have had to use python to generate documents for google sheets, when doing so the data would look something like this, where essentially each list is a row:

```
names = [['Name'], ['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
```

Going back to your problem, from my understanding, you want to essentially join each of these if they match.

```
names = [['Name'], ['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
data = [['Name', 'Server', 'IP-Address'], ['a', 'server1', '127.0.0.1'], ['b', 'server1', '127.0.0.1'], ['c', 'server2', '0.0.0.1']]

joined_data = []
for name, data in zip(names[1:], data[1:]):
    if name in data:
        joined_data.append(data)

print joined_data
```

Which produces the following output

```
[['a', 'server1', '127.0.0.1'], ['b', 'server1', '127.0.0.1'], ['c', 'server2', '0.0.0.1']]
```

---

You can make this more pythonic with a list comprehension though:

```
names = [['Name'], ['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
data = [['Name', 'Server', 'IP-Address'], ['a', 'server1', '127.0.0.1'], ['b', 'server1', '127.0.0.1']

joined_data = [data for name, data in zip(names[1:], data[1:]) if name[0] in data]
print joined_data
```

Which produces the following output

```
[['a', 'server1', '127.0.0.1'], ['b', 'server1', '127.0.0.1'], ['c', 'server2', '0.0.0.1']]
```

---

**Final Points**

As quoted in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel):

> In Python 2, zip returns a list of tuples. This is fine when foo and
>   bar are not massive. If they are both massive then forming
>   zip(foo,bar) is an unnecessarily massive temporary variable, and
>   should be replaced by itertools.izip

Which would look somewhat like this:

```
import itertools

names = [['Name'], ['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
data = [['Name', 'Server', 'IP-Address'], ['a', 'server1', '127.0.0.1'], ['b', 'server1', '127.0.0.1']

joined_data = [data for name, data in itertools.izip(names[1:], data[1:]) if name[0] in data]
print joined_data
```

Finally, the reason I do `...zip(names[1:], data[1:])`, is to eliminate the first "row" *(list)* of the data which is the headers as they aren't really the data we're dealing with.